# why does web page reload on Websocket.onmessage

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am writing a websocket based page, which is supposed to send a message, then get a bunch of messages, update the UI and wait for the next user action.

it seems, however, that every incoming messages (that is, multiple onmessage on the page) undoes what the previous one did, which is not what i want.

i added alerts, and it seems like on every send()'s receive, both $document.ready() and websocket.onload are called (though multiple messages to the same send do not do it). is there any way to prevent that, or must i maintain a local data structure? or maybe i need to send the entire data body on each message?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
var WS = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket;
var wsUri = "ws://localhost:9000/nodeWS";

window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

function init() {
  alert("init")
  $("#addNodeForm").submit(function(evt){
    addNode();
  }); 
  testWebSocket();
}

function testWebSocket() {
  /*var createSocket = new WS("@routes.Nodes.watchNodeCollection");*/
  if ('WebSocket' in window) {
    try{
      websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
  /*      alert("WebSocket created");*/
    } catch (e) {
      alert("exception creating WebSocket: " + e);
    }
  }
  else if ('MozWebSocket' in window) {
    try{
      websocket = new MozWebSocket(wsUri);
  /*      alert("MozWebSocket created");*/
    } catch (e) {
      alert("exception creating MozWebSocket: " + e);
    }
  }
  else {

    alert("no websocket support found");
  }   
  /*  alert("websocket created");*/
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
      alert("onopen")
      getAllNodes();
    };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { 
      onClose(evt);
      alert("onClose ended");
    };
  websocket.onmessage = receive
}

var receive = function onMessage(evt) { 
  evt.stopPropagation()
  evt.preventDefault()
  var data = JSON.parse(evt.data);

  if (data.error){   document.getElementById("messageBox").removeClass().addClass("errorbox").innerHTML(data.error).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(4000);
  } 
  if (data.message){
document.getElementById("messageBox").removeClass().addClass("confirmbox").innerHTML(data.message)/*.fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(4000);
  }
  if (data._id) { 
      addNodeRowToTable(data.doc);
  }
}
function addNodeRowToTable(data){
...add node to table...
}

function addNode() {
  var address = document.getElementById("address")

  websocket.send(JSON.stringify({
    type : "addNode",
    address : address.value.length>0 ? address.value : null
  }))      
}

function getAllNodes(){
  websocket.send(JSON.stringify(
      {
      type : "getAllNode"
    }
    )) 
}


var handleReturnKey = function(e) {
  if(e.charCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault()
    addNode()
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your code? It's hard to tell without seeing it.

Comment: added code to question